# pexpect behaves differently under cron

Tags: python, cron, pexpect

I have a script that behaves differently under cron than it does from the terminal.  In the terminal, it does what's expected and everything is sequential like it is written in the script.  Under cron, I have to add sleep calls to prevent pexpect from sending sigint to the child to kill it prematurely.  (yes, I spent an hour digging through strace output to figure this out).

```
def getLftpData(patterns):
   try:
      print(f"debug: getLftpData() called")
      child = pexpect.spawn("lftp", timeout=900)
      child.expect("lftp :~>")
      child.sendline("open ftp://ftp.somecompany.com")
      child.expect("ftp.somecompany.com:.>")
      child.sendline("login <username> <password>")
      child.expect("ftp.somecompany.com:.>")
      for pat in patterns:
         child.sendline(f"mirror --include-glob={pat}")
         child.expect("ftp.somecompany.com:.>")
         # sleep(60)  # This shouldn't be necessary
      print(f"debug: {str(child)}")
      child.sendline("QUIT")
      # sleep(30)  # This shouldn't be necessary
      child.close()
   except:
      print("Error retrieving data:\n")
      print(str(child))
```

Clearly, I still have some debug statements left in there and the code might not be perfect.  What I need to understand is why does this work from the terminal, but it fails under cron?  strace shows that the quit command is given to the client before the mirror command has finished processing.  Then, pexpect sends sighup followed by sigint a very short time later.  The sleep() calls got around the issue, I just need to know why.

Edit: clarified the example by commenting out the workaround.

Comment: Please post a [repro] or all the output on screen when you manually run all the commands.

Comment: "when you manually run all the commands"  Do you mean under cron or at the terminal?  It behaves differently depending on how it is run.  I will be limited on what I can post publicly.  As it is, I've had to change a fair bit so as to not divulge credentials or third parties involved in the transfer.  Further, what I have posted should be enough to reproduce, I think.

Comment: Expect-like scripts are timing sensitive and highly depend on how you manually interact with the spawned process.

Comment: To make a [repro] you can update your script by connecting to a public ftp site so others can try it and see where the issue is.

Comment: Will try and do as you suggest, but it will take time to adjust for the different server/file combination.  Not trying to split hairs, but one doesn't manually interact with a cron job.  The entire idea is to have a script run without interaction at a specified date/time.  Just want to ensure we are on the same page...

Comment: I did not mean interact with cron job. I mean how you interact with lftp. So just repro the issue with lftp to a pub ftp site.

Comment: After much finagling, I've managed to create and find some new problems.  The interaction between lftp and pexpect is complicated by the fact that lftp issues quite a few control codes to the screen to print status updates, typically printing a line, then clearing the line, then printing new status data.  I really need to get in contact with the maintainer to diagnose this, but the documentation says to post here.  Anyone know how I can get in contact with this person?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there hasn't been any additional information posted, so I decided to approach the problem in a different way.  I instead modified the program to write out a script for lftp to execute and then ran it under the subprocess module:

```
lftp -f lftpCmds.txt
```

Then, I remove/unlink the lftpCmds.txt file after it's done.  While this works, it is, in my opinion, not a lot better than the sleep() solution I was using before.  This is only better because it doesn't impose a time delay that really doesn't need to be there so the execution is a little quicker.